# php not outputing a ISO timestamp from mongoDB the format I need

Tags: php, mongodb, date

I need to have a time stamp that is like this: `2008-01-28T20:24:17Z` for a jQuery plugin however when I try to retrieve the date from a mongoDB using:

`<?php print date('c', $article['created_at']->sec);?>`

I get this back:  `2012-01-24T19:20:12+00:00`

Does anyone know how to change the timestamp to match the first ones formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', $article['created_at']->sec);
```

Both forms are valid for [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates though, if a program can parse one, it should be able to parse the other as well.

Comment: Thanks, I had to have it in this format for this plugin [prettydates](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-prettydate/)